# Why can't I create multiple files in the app directory with Qt on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt

I have a basic Android app with a push button that should create a file in the apps standard directory (`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.qtproject.example.MyApp/files/`) each time it's pushed.

This is the code beeing executed on each button push:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() {
    QString filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.qtproject.example.MyApp/files/" + "file_number_" + QString::number(counter);
    QFile myFile(filePath);

    if (myFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        myFile.write("foo");
        ++counter;
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Unable to open file" << filePath;
    }
```

It should create the files "file_number_0", "file_number_1", "file number_2" etc.

However it only seems to work for the first file. It does not create multiple files when pressed multiple times, but also does not throw an error for the following files. It does **not** print "Unable to open file". All files seem to get successfully opened, but only the inital file is actually created in the directory.

If I delete the app directory and create it again at runtime, the very next file will be created successfully again, but the following files won't, just like at the beginning.

Comment: This won't solve your problem but you should close the file after you write to it.

Comment: print out your `filePath` variable and make sure it is correct before you open: `qDebug()<<filePath;`

Comment: @RossRogers the `filePath` is `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.qtproject.example.myApp/files/file_number_0` , `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.qtproject.example.myApp/files/file_number_1` and so on. The path looks fine every time and does not seem to cause the problem.

Comment: You might have better luck using a relative path like `file_number_" + QString::number(counter)` instead of the full path.  That might be your app's "current working directory" aka $CWD.

Comment: Using a relative path does not seem to work at all. No files are created in `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.qtproject.example.myApp/files/` nor anywhere else on my phone. I checked what the cwd actually is with `QDir::currentPath()`, which returned `/data/data/org.qtproject.example.myApp/files`.

Comment: Files are weird on android.  Try the $CWD  method and then test if they are still there like  `qDebug()<< QFile::exists("file_number_1") ? "found it" : "can't find";`

Comment: @RossRogers It does indeed print "found it" for all the files

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that I was viewing the folder from my computer via USB. I assume that this somehow messes with Androids permission system.

I closed the file explorer on my computer and instead used the one on my phone and now it works.